# How do I bind the enter key to a function in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, key-bindings

I am a Python beginning self-learner, running on MacOS.

I'm making a program with a text parser GUI in tkinter, where you type a command in a `Entry` widget, and hit a `Button` widget, which triggers my `parse()` funct, ect, printing the results to a `Text` widget, text-adventure style.

> > Circumvent the button
>
> I can't let you do that, Dave.

I'm trying to find a way to get rid of the need to haul the mouse over to the `Button` every time the user issues a command, but this turned out harder than I thought.

I'm guessing the correct code looks like `self.bind('<Return>', self.parse())`? But I don't even know where to put it. `root`, `__init__`, `parse()`, and `create_widgets()` don't want it.

To be clear, the only reason anyone should hit enter in the prog is to trigger `parse()`, so it doesn't need to be espoused to the `Entry` widget specifically. Anywhere it works is fine.

In response to 7stud, the basic format:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font, random, re

class Application(Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, ...)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.start()

        
    def parse(self):
        ...


    def create_widgets(self):
        
        ...

        self.submit = Button(self, text= "Submit Command.", command= self.parse, ...)
        self.submit.grid(...)

        
root = Tk()
root.bind('<Return>', self.parse)

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try running the following program.  You just have to be sure your window has the focus when you hit Return--to ensure that it does, first click the button a couple of times until you see some output, then without clicking anywhere else hit Return.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

def func(event):
    print("You hit return.")
root.bind('<Return>', func)

def onclick():
    print("You clicked the button")

button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=onclick)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Then you just have tweak things a little when making both the `button click` and `hitting Return` call the same function--because the command function needs to be a function that takes no arguments, whereas the bind function needs to be a function that takes one argument(the event object):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

def func(event):
    print("You hit return.")

def onclick(event=None):
    print("You clicked the button")

root.bind('<Return>', onclick)

button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=onclick)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Or, you can just forgo using the button's command argument and instead use bind() to attach the onclick function to the button, which means the function needs to take one argument--just like with Return:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

def func(event):
    print("You hit return.")

def onclick(event):
    print("You clicked the button")

root.bind('<Return>', onclick)

button = tk.Button(root, text="click me")
button.bind('<Button-1>', onclick)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here it is in a class setting:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("300x200")

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.root.bind('<Return>', self.parse)
        self.grid()

        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit")
        self.submit.bind('<Button-1>', self.parse)
        self.submit.grid()

    def parse(self, event):
        print("You clicked?")

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


Application().start()
```

Comment: @Ghosty, I posted an example in a class setting. It's very important to remember that if you use the command argument to attach a handler function to a button, then the function cannot take any arguments.  On the other hand, if you use bind() to attach a handler function, the function must take one argument.  Look at the examples I posted to see how to deal with that.

Comment: Here is some documentation for handling events in tkinter. https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php

Answer (score 30):

Another alternative is to use a lambda:

```
ent.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: name_of_function()))
```

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def reply(name):
    showinfo(title="Reply", message = "Hello %s!" % name)


top = Tk()
top.title("Echo")

Label(top, text="Enter your name:").pack(side=TOP)
ent = Entry(top)
ent.bind("<Return>", (lambda event: reply(ent.get())))
ent.pack(side=TOP)
btn = Button(top,text="Submit", command=(lambda: reply(ent.get())))
btn.pack(side=LEFT)

top.mainloop()
```

As you can see, creating a lambda function with an unused variable "event" solves the problem.

Comment: Your code references a local image `Iconshock-Folder-Gallery.ico` other users don't have access to.

Comment: I must add that if you are binding events to a specific widget like an Entry in your example, that entry must first be in focus before the binding could take effect. e.g. user must be selecting that entry box. You can automate this by using ent.focus_set() to grab the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I found one good thing about using bind is that you get to know the trigger event: something like: "You clicked with event = [ButtonPress event state=Mod1 num=1 x=43 y=20]" due to the code below:

```
self.submit.bind('<Button-1>', self.parse)
def parse(self, trigger_event):
        print("You clicked with event = {}".format(trigger_event))
```

Comparing the following two ways of coding a button click:

```
btn = Button(root, text="Click me to submit", command=(lambda: reply(ent.get())))
btn = Button(root, text="Click me to submit")
btn.bind('<Button-1>', (lambda event: reply(ent.get(), e=event)))
def reply(name, e = None):
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Reply", message = "Hello {0}!\nevent = {1}".format(name, e))
```

The first one is using the command function which doesn't take an argument, so no event pass-in is possible.
The second one is a bind function which can take an event pass-in and print something like "Hello Charles! event = [ButtonPress event state=Mod1 num=1 x=68 y=12]"

We can left click, middle click or right click a mouse which corresponds to the event number of 1, 2 and 3, respectively. Code:

```
btn = Button(root, text="Click me to submit")
buttonClicks = ["<Button-1>", "<Button-2>", "<Button-3>"]
for bc in buttonClicks:
    btn.bind(bc, lambda e : print("Button clicked with event = {}".format(e.num)))
```

Output:

```
Button clicked with event = 1
Button clicked with event = 2
Button clicked with event = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me while assigning buttons to functions.**

*Create a function to set buttons to other functions:*

```
def enter(event=clr):
    but_ch['command'] = clr
```

*Then bind the function to the root and invoke:*

```
root.bind('<Return>', lambda enter: but_ch.invoke())
```