# How to bind the Enter key to a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button:

```
button3 = Button(app, text="Show Members", width=15, command=lambda: showLDAPMembers(yourName,yourPassword))
```

How do I bind the ENTER key to it? I tried doing:

```
app.bind('<Return>', showLDAPMembers(yourName,yourPassword))
```

but I get unresolved reference error..

```
def showLDAPMembers(yourName,yourPassword):
    app.lb.delete(0,END)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bind the enter key to a function in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996432/how-do-i-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-function-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a lambda if you're passing arguments.

```
app.bind("<Return>", lambda x: showLDAPMembers(yourName,yourPassword))
```

The `bind` command automatically returns the event that called it, so you need to define and throw away that (with `lambda x:`)

Comment: That did it, thanks..What if I have a more than one button that I'd like to bind the Enter key to? I need to have it bind the key to the button and the active entry? I have 2 fields, group1 and group2. I want to be able to type in group1, press Enter, see membership (lists in a listbox) and same with group2..

Comment: You can bind a key to an Entry, so when it is active, and a key is pressed, it will call your function: group1.bind('<Return>', lambda e: function(args)). http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: Three years and some later, I'd like to point out that it is perhaps more idiomatic to write this as `lambda evt: ...` or `lambda _: ...`. The former tells the reader what parameter you're expecting, and the latter tells the reader that you won't be using this parameter at all. `lambda x: ...` is, however, just lazy.

Answer (score 0):

first of all inside your function you need to

```
def showLDAPMembers(event= None)
```

then you can use the bind method to listen to your return key

```
app.bind("<Return>",showLDAPMembers())
```

I hope my answer helps you