# Bind 'Enter' on complicated Tkinter code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make some tweaks to code that I found on GitHub. The tkinter gui works perfectly but I want to bind the enter button to the 'Get Response' button:

```
class TkinterGUIExample(tk.Tk):

    def initialize(self):
        '''
        Set window layout.
        '''
        self.grid()

        self.usr_input = ttk.Entry(self, state='normal')
        self.usr_input.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)

        self.respond = ttk.Button(self, text='Get Response', command=self.get_response)
        self.respond.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)

        self.conversation_lbl = ttk.Label(self, anchor=tk.E, text='Conversation:')
        self.conversation_lbl.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)

        self.conversation = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self, state='disabled')
        self.conversation.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)
```

So I know where my button is, but I don't know how, when, or where to bind it, while using the same syntax.

My full code can be found here:
https://github.com/graylu21/ELIZA-ChatterBot/blob/master/ELIZAChatterBot.py

Comment: We don't want or need the full code. We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a binding to `'<Return>'`:

```
self.respond = ttk.Button(self, text='Get Response', command=self.get_response)
self.respond.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)
self.bind('<Return>', self.get_response)
```

Whenever you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> (Tkinter uses the latter because `'<Enter>'` refers to when the mouse cursor enters a widget) while the `self` window is active, it will call `self.get_response`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm getting a type error: get_response() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work! Found the solution in a comment at:
[How to bind the Enter key to a button in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943718/how-to-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-button-in-tkinter?rq=1)

Instead of binding the Enter key to the button, I bound it to the Entry window!

```
    self.usr_input = ttk.Entry(self, state='normal')
    self.usr_input.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)
    self.usr_input.focus() #Sets focus to the input bar at start
    self.usr_input.bind('<Return>', lambda e: self.get_response()) #Binds the Enter key

    self.respond = ttk.Button(self, text='Get Response', command=self.get_response)
    self.respond.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nesw', padx=3, pady=3)
```