# Entry widget Tkinter. I am getting confused

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to ask something that I think it may be very simple, but I can not get it!

I am using tkinter in python, and I am trying to build an entry. The text of this entry should be stored in a variable (I called it "s"). BUT, I want also that this widget works dynamicly. For example. I start the program, I introduce some text from the keyboard, and it is stored in "s", then I want to introduce something different, and now what the "s" variable stores is the new introduced text, not the old one. I wrote this code but my "s" variable always stores the original text.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x250")

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

e.delete(0, END)
e.insert(0, "a default value")
s = e.get()

print s
root.mainloop()
```

To introduce a text, Do I have to write it in the box, and then press Enter?
Thanks a lot
Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is entered during the mainloop. Use a callback (with a Button widget for example) to get your text.

For example, here is a callback using a `Button` :

```
from tkinter import *

def print_input(entry):
    print entry.get()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x250")
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()

b = Button(root, text="Print my input", command=lambda e=e: print_input(e))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can also bind the `<return>` key for all your window by using the following line :

```
def func(event):
    print("You hit return.")
root.bind('<Return>', func)
```

Here are some interesting ways to do it : [Can't figure out how to bind the enter key to a function in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996432/cant-figure-out-how-to-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-function-in-tkinter)