# How do I set a specific action to happen when the "enter" key on my keyboard is pressed in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a python calculator with GUI for school.

I have got some basic code from the internet and I have to customize it by changing things around. So far I have added a `DEL` button, a `^2` button and a `sqrt()` button.

I now want that if I type in an equation on my keyboard, e.g. "2*4", and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will simulate as pressing the equals button. I am having trouble finding out how to get python to register me clicking the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then give me an answer.

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
from math import *
from functools import partial
try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # the root will be self
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Magic")
        # use width x height + x_offset + y_offset (no spaces!)
        #self.geometry("300x150+150+50")
        # or set x, y position only
        self.geometry("+150+50")
        self.memory = 0
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        # this also shows the calculator's button layout
        btn_list = [
        '7',  '8',  '9',  '*',  'AC',
        '4',  '5',  '6',  '/',  'x²',
        '1',  '2',  '3',  '-',  '√x',
        '0',  '.',  '=',  '+',  'DEL' ]
        rel = 'ridge'
        # create all buttons with a loop
        r = 1
        c = 0
        for b in btn_list:
            # partial takes care of function and argument
            cmd = partial(self.calculate, b)
            tk.Button(self, text=b, width=5, relief=rel,
                command=cmd).grid(row=r, column=c)
            c += 1
            if c > 4:
                c = 0
                r += 1
        # use an Entry widget for an editable display
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=37, bg="white")
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

    def undo():
            new_string = whole_string[:-1]
            print(new_string)
            clear_all()
            display.insert(0, new_string)

    def calculate(self, key):
        if key == '=':
            # here comes the calculation part
            try:
                result = eval(self.entry.get())
                self.entry.insert(tk.END, " = " + str(result))
            except:
                self.entry.insert(tk.END, "")
        elif key == 'AC':
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        elif key == 'x²':
            self.entry.insert(tk.END, "**")
            # extract the result
        elif key == '√x':
            self.memory = self.entry.get()
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.entry.insert(tk.END, "sqrt(")
            self.entry.insert(tk.END, self.memory)
            self.entry.insert(tk.END, ")")
        elif key == 'DEL':
            self.memory = self.entry.get()
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.entry.insert(tk.END, self.memory[:-1])

        else:# previous calculation has been done, clear entry
            if '=' in self.entry.get():
                self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.entry.insert(tk.END, key)

app = MyApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please make the code readable!

Comment: Sorry i was just making a new post with the code like that, sorry first time user.

Comment: you can `bind()` function to `Entry` to control keys ie. `self.entry.bind('<Return>', function_name)` See [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: @DylanH . No problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't figure out how to bind the enter key to a function in tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996432/cant-figure-out-how-to-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-function-in-tkinter)

Comment: @furas Thanks for that. Is this how it should go?   

`def entersolve(event):
        print("You hit return")
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', entersolve)`

Comment: @furas So in theory when i press the return key it will now print "you hit return"?

Comment: Yes it should print  `"you hit return"`

Comment: in `entersolver` you can use `event.widget.get()` to get text from `self.entry`.

Comment: @furas On hitting the return key i get no response whatsoever.

Comment: which Return - left or right on numerical keyboard - they have different code ?

Comment: @furas Have tried both.

Comment: @furas Do I have to inform Python to wait or look for the return key to be pressed or should see the key press regardless?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind()` to assign function to `Entry` which will be executed when you press `Enter`

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_return(event):
    print('keycode:', event.keycode)
    print('text in entry:', event.widget.get())

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Return>', on_return)   # standard Enter
e.bind('<KP_Enter>', on_return) # KeyPad Enter

root.mainloop()
```

In your code it can be - for test

```
self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=37, bg="white")
self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

self.entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event:print("ENTER:", event.widget.get()))
self.entry.bind('<KP_Enter>', lambda event:print("ENTER:", event.widget.get()))
```

If you have class method `def on_return(self, event):` then

```
self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.on_return)
self.entry.bind('<KP_Enter>', self.on_return)
```

---

1. [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)
2. [Key names](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: Thanks for that. I might see if i can familiarize myself with python a little bit more and try making my own calculator. It might help me understand everything a bit better.

Comment: After adding the `self.entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event:print("ENTER:", event.widget.get()))` I can confirm it now respond to my key press.