# Binding a Keyboard Key to a Function - Python KeyListener

Tags: python, python-3.x, listener, key-bindings

> "You've pressed the Enter Key!"

**Whenever I press Key(z) the function should be executed:**

```
#Pseudocode:
bind(<Enter>, function_x)
```

---

I'm currently working on a python program, which will run in a *constant loop*. It runs only on the console *(no GUI)*, but still I need to be able to *interact* with the program *at any time* without having the program *asking for input.*

Comment: The mainloop is what makes it *possible* for Tkinter to respond to keyboard events at arbitrary times.  Try `pynput`, it has the ability to install a keyboard listener (which is basically an event loop running in another thread), but note that callbacks from the listener will necessarily be running in that thread, NOT your main thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Several Modules solve this Problem

**Pynput** 
(`pip install pynput`)

*Simple module for handling and controlling general inputs*

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key

def on_press(key):
    #handle pressed keys
    pass

def on_release(key):
    #handle released keys
    if(key==Key.enter):
        function_x()

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

(See [pynput docs](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/))

---

**Keyboard** (`pip install keyboard`)

*A simple module for simulating and handling keyboard input*

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', lambda: function_x())
```

(See [Keyboard docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard))

---

**Tkinter**

*Integrated UI Module, can track inputs on focused thread*

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk() #also works on other TK widgets
root.bind("<Enter>", function_x)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**Be aware:** These solutions all use Threading in some way. You might not be able to execute other code after you've started listening for keys.

Helpful threads:
[KeyListeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python), [Binding in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996432/how-do-i-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-function-in-tkinter)

**feel free to add more solutions**

Answer (score 0):

No beans with module keyboard.

Simply way to clear screen:

```
print('\033[2J') # clear screen, but stay current cursor line
print('\033[H') # move cursor 1,1 home position

or

print('\033[H\033[2J') # one step to clear screen and move at home position
```

You may define function like:

```
def cls():
    print('\033[H\033[2J')
```

It works with tedious call braces.

I like to bind previous functionality to keyboard 'scroll lock' key, but how?