# How can I bind the enter key to a command while having a button do the same thing?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function whiten class. There is also a button which activates the function. I also want to make it so the user can press the enter key and it would run the function.

my current code looks something like this (simplified)

```
myButton = Button(text = "My Button", command = self.myFunction)
root.bind('<Return>', self.myFunction2)

def myFunction(self):
   pass

def myFunction(self, event):
   pass
```

I am using 2 functions because another answer on here said that it would work if I added another argument to one of the function (called event in this case)

This code works but I want to find a more efficient way to do this as each function is quite long and it is a hassle to change both of them when Im making a change.

if I try bind the enter key to myFunction(self), I get an error saying that 2 positional retirements wee given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bind the enter key to a function in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996432/how-do-i-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-function-in-tkinter)

Comment: ***"do the same thing?"***: Why, would you do so? You are misguided, `Button(..., command=...)` is event `'<Button-1>'` and not `'<Return>'`

Answer (score 2):

Define your function as

```
def myFunction(self, event=None):
```

This will accept being called with or without the `event` argument. `None` is used as the default value for `event` when it isn't passed.